# How to setup a docker dev environment for my team to work on?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need to set up an environment with docker, containing multiple technologies such as a BD, a test environment, continuous integration, and some other things. I also need it to be available for my teammates to use.

I'm don't quite understand docker beyond the high-level concept of it so I have no idea where to start from. Useful answers would go from a step-by-step how to do it, to simply pointing me towards the right links for my problem. Thank you!

We intend to use either:

- PostgreSQL
- Node.js
- Vue
- Jenkins

, or:

- PostgreSQL
- Android Studio
- Jenkins

Comment: You may read https://docs.docker.com/ for both `docker-compose` and `Dockerfile`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question about sharing a dev docker with teammates you need to have 2 different docker-compose files in your project like dev and prod.

on the other hand when your not yet comfortable with docker you better get involve with it step by step.

1. learn about making an stateless application, because when you are working with docker you want to scale horizontally later on
2. dockerize your apps (learn how to make a docker file for your nodejs project)
3. learn how to make a docker-compose file for nodejs + postgres application test it and make sure they are connected and are in one docker network which you created in docker-compose
4. you need a docker repository like docker hub or your own repo installation like nexus to push your production ready code after jenkins automated tests which then you can deploy
5. you can put your front and back end in one docker-compose file but i wouldn't recommend it because, multiple teams should work with one docker-compose file which might at first confuses them
6. you can ask your devOps team for Jenkins installation and create your CI yaml files
7. docker-compose files that you would create would be in the project directory and any one who clones the project would have access to it
8. create a read-me file with clear instructions for building, testing and deployment of the project for both dev and prod environment.

i don't know this would help or not because your question was not specific but i hope it will.